# How to control beam deflection through a risley prism?

Tags: geometric-optics

I am trying to estimate the output angles for the following optical setup.

[Only for Risley Prism]

According to this source [here](https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/optomech/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2016/10/for-Mark.pdf) (first orientation setup), the output beam is parallel to the optical axis, if the incoming beam is also parallel. But how do I get a parallel beam at the output for the arbitrary incident angles? The rotation of one prism compared to the other will deviate the ray from the optical axis. Should I rotate the prisms(both) in the opposite direction to compensate for the deviation? Is there a general mathematical model for arbitrary angles?

PS: I want to manipulate the rotation of the Risley prism so that I get a normal incident beam at the beamsplitter.

[image: My setup]